# Properly handling Escape Characters in Boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have a S3 Bucket Streaming logs to a lambda function that tags files based on some logic.

While I have worked around this issue in the past and [I understand](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/object-keys.html) there are some characters that need to be handled I'm wondering if there is a safe way to handle this with some API or is it something I need to handle on my own.

For example I have a lambda function like so:

```py
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    s3 = boto3.client("s3")

    for record in event["Records"]:
        bucket = record["s3"]["bucket"]["name"]
        objectName = record["s3"]["object"]["key"]

        tags = []
        
        if "Pizza" in objectName:
            tags.append({"Key" : "Project", "Value" : "Great"})
        if "Hamburger" in objectName:
            tags.append({"Key" : "Project", "Value" : "Good"})
        if "Liver" in objectName:
            tags.append({"Key" : "Project", "Value" : "Yuck"})

        s3.put_object_tagging(
            Bucket=bucket,
            Key=objectName,
            Tagging={
                "TagSet" : tags
            }
        )

    
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
    }
```

This code works great. I upload a file to s3 called `Pizza-Is-Better-Than-Liver.txt` then the function runs and tags the file with both `Great` and `Yuck` (sorry for the strained example).

However If I upload the file `Pizza Is+AmazeBalls.txt` things go sideways:

Looking at the event in CloudWatch the object key shows as: `Pizza+Is%2BAmazeBalls.txt`.

Obviously the space is escaped to a `+` and the `+` to a `%2B` when I pass that key to `put_object_tagging()` it fails with a `NoSuchKey` Error.

**My question;** is there a defined way to deal with escaped characters in boto3 or some other sdk, or do I just need to do it myself? I really don't and to add any modules to the function and I could just use do a contains / replace(), but it's odd I would get something back that I can't immediately use without some transformation.

I'm not uploading the files and can't mandate what they call things (i-have-tried-but-it-fails), if it's a valid Windows or Mac filename it should work (I get that is a whole other issue but I can deal with that).

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

So after some comments on the [GitHub](https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/3584) I should have been using [urllib.parse.unquote_plus](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.unquote_plus) in this situation. this would be the proper way to solve escaping issues like this.

```py
from urllib.parse import unquote_plus
print(unquote_plus("Pizza+Is%2BAmazeBalls.txt"))
# Pizza Is+AmazeBalls.txt
```

**Original Answer:**

Since no other answers I guess I post my bandaid:

```py
def format_path(path):
    path = path.replace("+", " ")
    path = path.replace("%21", "!")
    path = path.replace("%24", "$")
    path = path.replace("%26", "&")
    path = path.replace("%27", "'")
    path = path.replace("%28", "(")
    path = path.replace("%29", ")")
    path = path.replace("%2B", "+")
    path = path.replace("%40", "@")
    path = path.replace("%3A", ":")
    path = path.replace("%3B", ";")
    path = path.replace("%2C", ",")
    path = path.replace("%3D", "=")
    path = path.replace("%3F", "?")
    return path
```

I'm sure there is a simpler, more complete way to do this but this seems to work... for now.